# What is a good multithreading book for Delphi?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

Where can I get a good book on Delphi threading. Something that will suit a total newcomer to the subject.

Comment: When *I* ask questions like this, I am murderously downvoted... :( How did you manage to get *13* upvotes man?

Comment: @SAM by asking in 2009

Answer (score 14):

Not a book, but the article [*Multithreading – The Delphi Way*, by Martin Harvey](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item.aspx?id=14809), is a great start.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have some reading to go and do.

Comment: Yes, it's not a book. But it has chapters, so it's much more than just an article.

Answer (score 6):

The book  [Delphi™ 6 Developer’s Guide from Steve Teixeira and Xavier Pacheco](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672321157) has a full chapter called "Multithreaded Techniques". This is an excellent book .

[image]

Also you can check this serie of articles from [the delphi corner site](http://www.delphicorner.f9.co.uk/)

- [Waiting for Threads](http://www.delphicorner.f9.co.uk/articles/op1.htm)
- [Running Queries in Threads](http://www.delphicorner.f9.co.uk/articles/db1.htm)
- [Creating threads straight from the WinAPI](http://www.delphicorner.f9.co.uk/articles/op2.htm)
- [How to interrupt a thread's execution](http://www.delphicorner.f9.co.uk/articles/op3.htm)
- [**Thread Synchronization through Critical Sections**](http://www.delphicorner.f9.co.uk/articles/op4.htm)

From Embarcadero

- [Using Semaphores in Delphi, Part 1](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29908)
- [Using Semaphores in Delphi, Part 2: The Connection Pool](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/30027)

Bye.

Comment: Great reference book! I'd love to see someone release an updated version of this book.

Answer (score 2):

This is also NOT a book. But I too found threading in Delphi very difficult when I started trying to learn it.

Rather than try to learn all its complexities, one alternative I might suggest is to try the OmniThreadLibrary at http://otl.17slon.com/  To me it simplifies everything. And it has a FAQ, tutorial and forum.

You might also want to check out the StackOverflow question: [Delphi - Threading frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670641/delphi-threading-frameworks)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of tutorials, articles and tips on threading in Delphi (not a book, though):

http://delphi.about.com/od/kbthread/Threading_in_Delphi.htm